# how to get the IP of my device and the server IP (windows-CE)

Tags: c#, windows-ce

how do i get my IP and the server's IP in windows-CE (using C#)?

Comment: does **Dns.GetHostName();** exists in Compact framework? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostname.aspx

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "server IP".  Do you know the host name of the server and you want to know the IPv4 address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is vague.  I don't know which adapter or type of address you want, so I assume you want the IPv4 address of the first local adapter.  That would look something like this:

```
var ip = (from a in Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
     where a.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork
      select a).First().ToString();
```

Getting the IP address of a given server would require that you know it's hostname and then you'd do a lookup (i.e. `Dns.GetHostEntry`) on that name.  It would look a lot like the code above, except you'd use the server host name instead of the `Dns.GetHostName()` call.

Answer (score 0):

It involves some P/Invoke magic.  Because it is a lot of code and what I have is partially proprietary, I can't post all of it, but I can give some hints.

```
// MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917(v=vs.85).aspx
[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int GetAdaptersInfo(IntPtr pAdapterInfo, ref int pOutBufLen);

[DllImport("iphlpapi.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern int GetAdapterIndex(string AdapterName, ref int IfIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I've run into this exact problem recently. Since we already use OpenNETCF, I used this library to query my NICs and their associated addresses. This was on Windows Mobile 6.5 (CE 5.2).

```
var ifs = OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
foreach (var nic in ifs)
{
  IPAddress myip = nic.CurrentIpAddress;
}
```

This will work even if DNS is not configured.